# React - Race Condition in multiple useEffect's cleanup function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, race-condition

I have a component that

1. Initiate a websocket ref on mount (`endpoint` prop doesn't change)
2. When component comes into screen view, it calls the `subscribe` on `wsRef`
3. When component goes out of screen view, it calls the `unsubscribe` on `wsRef`

The problem is on `unmount` the 2nd cleanup function fails because we already have closed the websocket by the 1st cleanup function.

So we are unable to `unsubscribe` as the websocket is not in `OPEN` state.

How to control the order of cleanup effects here?

```
function Comp({endpoint, isVisible, id}) {
  const wsRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    wsRef.current = new WebsocketClass(endpoint);
    return () => {              // [1] cleanup no 1
      wsRef.current.close();
      wsRef.current = null;
    }
  }, [endpoint]);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (isVisible) {
      wsRef.current.subscribe(id);
    }
    return () => {
      if (isVisible) {
        wsRef.current.unsubscribe(id); // [2] fails, this cleanup runs after [1]
      } 
    }
  }, [isVisible, id]);

}
```

If I re-order the two `useEffect` in my function, the problem seem to go away, but is it really a permanent solution here?

Also, I can't `close` the websocket in the `unsubscribe` cleanup because the component can stay mounted while it goes out of screen and comes back again as user scrolls back and forth.

Comment: Since the socket disconnection clears the ref, how about `wsRef.current?.unsubscribe(id)`? It would just skip unsubscribing if the socket is closed because closing the socket presumable also removes any subscription. If not, I would see a "unsubscribe all" logic for closing.

Comment: Switching the effect order was going to be my suggestion, and I see you've mentioned doing so and the issue went away. If the issue is resolved this way what is the concern?

Comment: @DrewReese is that the right way to handle this? It looks like a house of cards, to get the order of effects right otherwise the app fails to work the right way.

Comment: If the order of the side-effects matter, then yes, it seems correct. Unsubscribing before closing seems logical to me. Like Jakub said though, it may be the case that closing the socket unsubscribes, but it may be better to be explicit.